# Can I POST multiple patch requests to RavenDB's /bulk_docs HTTP API endpoint?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-http

I'm in the process of writing a node wrapper for RavenDB.

I'm using version 3 but as there are no HTTP docs for it, I've been relying on the 2.0 and 2.5 docs.

In regards to single document operations, I've used [this doc page](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/http-api/http-api-single) successfully for PUTs, DELETEs and multiple PATCHs to individual documents.

Similarly, I've used [this doc page](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/http-api/http-api-multi) successfully for multiple PUTs and DELETEs of several documents in one HTTP call **but the docs are a bit vague in regards to PATCHing mutliple documents in one call**.

Under the "Batching Requests" heading, it clearly states it's possible:

> Request batching in RavenDB is handled using the '/bulk_docs' endpoint, which accepts an array of operations to execute. The format for the operations is:
>
> method - PUT, PATCH or DELETE.
>
> ...

For PUTs, I POST to /bulk_docs:

```
[
  {
    Method: 'PUT',
    Key: 'users/1',
    Document: { username: 'dummy' }
    Metadata: { 'Raven-Entity-Type': 'Users' }
  },
  ...
]
```

For DELETEs, I POST to /bulk_docs:

```
[
  {
    Method: 'DELETE',
    Key: 'users/1'
  },
  ...
]
```

For PATCHs, I've tried POSTing the following without any luck:

```
[
  {
    Method: 'PATCH',
    Key: 'users/1',
    Document: {
      Type: 'Set',
      Name:'username',
      Value: 'new-username'
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

and

```
[
  {
    Method: 'PATCH',
    Key: 'users/1',
    Type: 'Set',
    Name:'username',
    Value: 'new-username'
  },
  ...
]
```

All I'm getting back is `500 - Internal Server Error` and without any examples of PATCHing multiple documents on that docs page I'm kind of stuck...

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure for PATCH is :

```
[
  {
    Method: 'PATCH',
    Key: 'users/1',
    Patches: [{
Type: 'Set',
        Name:'username',
        Value: 'new-username'
}]
  },
  ...
]
```

The full structure can be see here:
https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Abstractions/Commands/PatchCommandData.cs#L72

Comment: Thanks @Ayende. I had a trawl through the source code late last night and figured it out. I'll try to use it more often in the future.